# In RDS, "serverTimezone=GMT%2B8" causes datetime to be one hour off

Tags: java, mysql, amazon-rds

If I use the MySQL connection option `serverTimezone=GMT%2B8`, then in 10% of the cases I get a result of one hour earlier.

for example, `2021-08-08 00:00:00` becomes `2021-08-07 23:00:00`.

After I change the option to `&serverTimezone=Asia/Shanghai`, everything is normal.

Why?

Comment: Probably because that *is* your timezone ;)

Comment: Asia/Shanghai alternates between UTC+8 and UTC+9, so it's not surprising that the results would differ, if you specify a date/time which is in a period where it's UTC+9.

Comment: Odd: Asia/Shanghai and UTC+8 should be the same. You may have DST in the summer so you effectively switch to UTC+9 (idk but maybe asia/shangai may take DST into account)

Comment: Ooh, hang on - no, Asia/Shanghai stopped observing DST in 1991. So I'd expect data *before* that to potentially be incorrect, but after that it should be the same. But fundamentally, if you're trying to represent a specific time zone rather than a UTC offset, it's best to use that time zone.